# Modify stored procedure to return data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is looking if any company has same number and return true or false related to this.

This is the code of my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [CoDb].[CompanyAttribute_RunDataValidation]
    @AttributeId INT,
    @Value VARCHAR(255),
    @ValidationType SMALLINT,
    @Operation SMALLINT,
    @CompanyId INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ValidationSuccess AS BIT = 1

    --Create operation
    IF @Operation = 1
    BEGIN
        --Unique validation
        IF @ValidationType = 1
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [CoDb].[CompanyAttribute] CA 
                      WHERE CA.AttributeId = @AttributeId 
                        AND CA.Value = @Value AND CA.IsDeleted = 0)
                SET @ValidationSuccess = 0
        END
    END
    --Update operation
    ELSE IF @Operation = 2
    BEGIN
        --Unique validation
        IF @ValidationType = 1
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [CoDb].[CompanyAttribute] CA 
                      WHERE CA.AttributeId = @AttributeId 
                        AND CA.Value = @Value AND CA.CompanyId <> @CompanyId 
                        AND CA.IsDeleted = 0)
                SET @ValidationSuccess = 0
        END
    END

    SELECT @ValidationSuccess
END
```

Now it returns just `true` or `false`.

I want it to return 2 value: 1 - true or false and `companyName` from selected company

I rewrote my stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [CoDb].[CompanyAttribute_RunDataValidation]
    @AttributeId INT,
    @Value VARCHAR(255),
    @ValidationType SMALLINT,
    @Operation SMALLINT,
    @CompanyId INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ValidationSuccess AS BIT = 1
    DECLARE @CompanyName AS VARCHAR(255) = ''

    --Create operation
    IF @Operation = 1
    BEGIN
        --Unique validation
        IF @ValidationType = 1
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT *  
                      FROM [CoDb].[CompanyAttribute] CA 
                      INNER JOIN [CoDb].[Company] C on C.Id = CA.CompanyId 
                      WHERE CA.AttributeId = @AttributeId 
                        AND CA.Value = @Value AND CA.IsDeleted = 0)
                SET @ValidationSuccess = 0
            SET @CompanyName = 
        END
    END
    --Update operation
    ELSE IF @Operation = 2
    BEGIN
        --Unique validation
        IF @ValidationType = 1
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT *  
                      FROM [CoDb].[CompanyAttribute] CA 
                      INNER JOIN [CoDb].[Company] C on C.Id = CA.CompanyId 
                      WHERE CA.AttributeId = @AttributeId 
                        AND CA.Value = @Value AND CA.CompanyId <> @CompanyId 
                        AND CA.IsDeleted = 0)
                SET @ValidationSuccess = 0
        END
    END

    SELECT @ValidationSuccess
END
```

But how I can get field from select, for example `CompanyName`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
--Create operation
IF @Operation = 1
BEGIN
    --Unique validation
    IF @ValidationType = 1
        IF EXISTS (SELECT *  
                   FROM [CoDb].[CompanyAttribute] CA 
                   INNER JOIN [CoDb].[Company] C ON C.Id = CA.CompanyId 
                   WHERE CA.AttributeId = @AttributeId 
                     AND CA.Value = @Value AND CA.IsDeleted = 0)
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                C.CompanyName, 0 AS ValidationSuccess
            FROM [CoDb].[Company] C 
            WHERE C.Id = @CompanyId 

            RETURN
        END
END
```

You basically need to use a `SELECT` to "build" the result set to be returned as a result of the stored procedure.

Comment: `WHERE on C.Id = @CompanyId`


I guess here we don't need on?

Comment: @EugeneSukh: right - sorry - copy&paste leftover ;-) Fixed it , thanks